# Sending data to statsd does not work in some locations with content_by_lua_file

Tags: nginx, lua, statsd

### Before

Until recently I used nginx 1.4.x with [zebrafishlabs/nginx-statsd](https://github.com/zebrafishlabs/nginx-statsd) as a reverse proxy for openresty (yes, I know, nginx behind nginx is stupid - keep reading please) with the following location nginx configuration:

```
location /track {
  statsd_count "tracker.track_$scheme" 1;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:10081/track;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

..and the following location openresty (listening on port 10081 TCP, of course) config:

```
location /track {
  content_by_lua_file 'conf/track.lua';
}
```

..and it worked. Please note that I have a few locations like that - it is important, you will see later on.

Stats were being pushed to statsd and the scripts were executed.

---

### Now

Recently I decided to remove the front end nginx and use openresty alone.

Now I am using openresty 1.5.12.1 with zebrafishlabs/nginx-statsd compiled in and the following (obvious) configuration:

```
location /track {
  statsd_count "tracker.track_$scheme" 1;
  content_by_lua_file 'conf/track.lua';
}
```

But after this change **sometimes my stats are not being pushed to statsd**.

**Apparently it happens if my lua script end execution with ngx.redirect lua command.**.

I tried to use this config as a workaround:

```
location /track {
  statsd_count "tracker.track_$scheme" 1;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/track-do;
}

location /track-do {
  content_by_lua_file 'conf/track.lua';
}
```

...but I got really strange results:

When I changed my "track" location this way it started to work properly - all stats pushed to statsd, code executed.

..but at the same time my other location, "static", that was not changed stopped pushing *anything* to statsd (!).

I think it is related to nginx processing phases. zebrafishlabs/nginx-statsd does do logging in the last, log phase while content_by_lua_file is processed in the content phase and ngx.redirect's that my scripts use documentation states that it "(...) terminates the current request's processing and never returns." but proxy_pass is also in the content phase and statsd directives were run when I used them together in nginx...

**1. Can you help me in this specific problem?**

**2. Do you have any success using zebrafishlabs/nginx-statsd with openresty? How do you do that?**

PS I already thought of using [lonelyplanet/openresty-statsd](https://github.com/lonelyplanet/openresty-statsd) and it would probably be a working workaround but I would have to move all my statsd usage inside my script which I do not want to keep them clean.

**UPDATE:** lonelyplanet/openresty-statsd way also didn't work!?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I made a workaround - started writing access logs to a file, analyze them by [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash) and its [statsd output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-statsd.html). It works.